# How to assign grade from a list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am creating a program that takes users and stores them in list and takes their marks and afterwards it grades them. I've done the user input part and the marks as well along with the average of them but I am struggling to give them grade and print it along with their name so it will be like Name marks Grade. If anyone can help me with this I'll be thankful greatly here is my code

```
students=[] 
for i in range (2):
    x=(input("Enter Student Name. \n")) 
    students.insert(i,x)
    i+=1
print(students)



grades = []
for student in students:
    grade = eval(input(f"Enter the grade for {student}: "))
    grades.append(grade)

result = list(zip(students, grades))
print(result)


average = sum(grades) / len(grades)
print ( "Average is: " + str(average))
total = sum(grades)
# print ("Total is: " + str(total))
print("Highest marks", max(list(zip(grades, students))))
print("Lowest marks", min(list(zip(grades, students))))

## To do assign grades to each according to their marks
```

Comment: 1) why `students.insert(i,x)` ? 2) why `eval(input(f"Enter the grade for {student}: "))`?

Comment: 1 because i want to take number of students approx 30. 2 -  Nothing is wrong with it I'm just taking grades from student

Comment: 1) `append` is enough here 2) No need for `eval` 3) No need for `i+=1`

Comment: Alright thanks but that's better approach but what I want can you please suggest that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am struggling to give them grade and print it along with their name so it will be like Name marks Grade.

Look at the below -  it uses zip and loop

```
names = ['Jack','Dan']
grades = [67,86]

def _get_grade(grade):
  if grade < 50:
    return 'C'
  elif grade >= 50 and grade <= 75:
    return 'B'
  else:
    return 'A'
for name,grade in zip(names,grades):
  print(f'Name: {name} - Grade: {_get_grade(grade)}')
```

Comment: Not this grade I want to print Alphabetical grade like A grade if the numbers are more than 80

Comment: @Aliumer Got it. See updated answer.

Comment: @Aliumer Glad I massaged to help. Please accept the answer.

Comment: Done thanks again